# Hudson with active directory error

Tags: apache-2.2, active-directory, hudson

first question here on superuser (i'm addicted on stackoverflow).

So, I'm trying to configure the active directory plugin (1.31-h1 version) on Hudson (3.0.1-b2) but without success. On the security screen configuration there is the option which I choose `Active Directory` then I click on Advanced button and put my domain controller `mydomain.com.br` this works smoothly, but when I choose the option  `Matrix security` and try to add a user from my domain it shows me a link `ERROR` when I click it, it shows me an 403 http error (forbidden).

So, to try to figure out what the error is I went to the tomcat log and there is an error saying that it can't find information for `myuser`

```
Jun 4, 2014 7:20:36 AM hudson.plugins.active_directory.ActiveDirectoryUnixAuthenticationProvider retrieveUser
WARNING: Failed to retrieve user information for myuser
javax.naming.NamingException: [LDAP: error code 1 - 00000000: LdapErr: DSID-0C090627, comment: In order to perform this operation a successful bind must be completed on the connection., data 0, vece]; remaining name 'DC=mydomain,DC=com,DC=br'
    at com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtx.mapErrorCode(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtx.processReturnCode(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtx.processReturnCode(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtx.searchAux(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtx.c_search(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtx.c_search(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.jndi.toolkit.ctx.ComponentDirContext.p_search(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.jndi.toolkit.ctx.PartialCompositeDirContext.search(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.jndi.toolkit.ctx.PartialCompositeDirContext.search(Unknown Source)
    at hudson.plugins.active_directory.LDAPSearchBuilder.search(LDAPSearchBuilder.java:52)
    at hudson.plugins.active_directory.LDAPSearchBuilder.searchOne(LDAPSearchBuilder.java:42)
    at hudson.plugins.active_directory.ActiveDirectoryUnixAuthenticationProvider.retrieveUser(ActiveDirectoryUnixAuthenticationProvider.java:260)
    at hudson.plugins.active_directory.ActiveDirectoryUnixAuthenticationProvider.retrieveUser(ActiveDirectoryUnixAuthenticationProvider.java:190)
    at hudson.plugins.active_directory.ActiveDirectoryUnixAuthenticationProvider.retrieveUser(ActiveDirectoryUnixAuthenticationProvider.java:134)
    at hudson.plugins.active_directory.AbstractActiveDirectoryAuthenticationProvider.loadUserByUsername(AbstractActiveDirectoryAuthenticationProvider.java:30)
    at hudson.plugins.active_directory.ActiveDirectorySecurityRealm.loadUserByUsername(ActiveDirectorySecurityRealm.java:611)
(...) some more stack
Jun 4, 2014 7:20:36 AM hudson.plugins.active_directory.ActiveDirectoryUnixAuthenticationProvider retrieveUser
WARNING: Credential exception tying to authenticate against mydomain.com.br domain
org.springframework.security.BadCredentialsException: Failed to retrieve user information for myuser; nested exception is javax.naming.NamingException: [LDAP: error code 1 - 00000000: LdapErr: DSID-0C090627, comment: In order to perform this operation a successful bind must be completed on the connection., data 0, vece]; remaining name 'DC=mydomain,DC=com,DC=br'
    at hudson.plugins.active_directory.ActiveDirectoryUnixAuthenticationProvider.retrieveUser(ActiveDirectoryUnixAuthenticationProvider.java:306)
    at hudson.plugins.active_directory.ActiveDirectoryUnixAuthenticationProvider.retrieveUser(ActiveDirectoryUnixAuthenticationProvider.java:190)
    at hudson.plugins.active_directory.ActiveDirectoryUnixAuthenticationProvider.retrieveUser(ActiveDirectoryUnixAuthenticationProvider.java:134)
    at hudson.plugins.active_directory.AbstractActiveDirectoryAuthenticationProvider.loadUserByUsername(AbstractActiveDirectoryAuthenticationProvider.java:30)
    at hudson.plugins.active_directory.ActiveDirectorySecurityRealm.loadUserByUsername(ActiveDirectorySecurityRealm.java:611)
    at hudson.security.GlobalMatrixAuthorizationStrategy$DescriptorImpl.doCheckName(GlobalMatrixAuthorizationStrategy.java:315)
    at hudson.security.GlobalMatrixAuthorizationStrategy$DescriptorImpl.doCheckName(GlobalMatrixAuthorizationStrategy.java:298)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
(...) some more stack
Caused by: javax.naming.NamingException: [LDAP: error code 1 - 00000000: LdapErr: DSID-0C090627, comment: In order to perform this operation a successful bind must be completed on the connection., data 0, vece]; remaining name 'DC=mydomain,DC=com,DC=br'
    at com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtx.mapErrorCode(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtx.processReturnCode(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtx.processReturnCode(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtx.searchAux(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtx.c_search(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtx.c_search(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.jndi.toolkit.ctx.ComponentDirContext.p_search(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.jndi.toolkit.ctx.PartialCompositeDirContext.search(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.jndi.toolkit.ctx.PartialCompositeDirContext.search(Unknown Source)
    at hudson.plugins.active_directory.LDAPSearchBuilder.search(LDAPSearchBuilder.java:52)
    at hudson.plugins.active_directory.LDAPSearchBuilder.searchOne(LDAPSearchBuilder.java:42)
    at hudson.plugins.active_directory.ActiveDirectoryUnixAuthenticationProvider.retrieveUser(ActiveDirectoryUnixAuthenticationProvider.java:260)
    ... 75 more
Jun 4, 2014 7:20:36 AM hudson.plugins.active_directory.ActiveDirectoryUnixAuthenticationProvider retrieveUser
WARNING: Failed to retrieve user information for t01brq0009
javax.naming.NamingException: [LDAP: error code 1 - 00000000: LdapErr: DSID-0C090627, comment: In order to perform this operation a successful bind must be completed on the connection., data 0, vece]; remaining name 'DC=mydomain,DC=com,DC=br'
    at com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtx.mapErrorCode(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtx.processReturnCode(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtx.processReturnCode(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtx.searchAux(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtx.c_search(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtx.c_search(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.jndi.toolkit.ctx.ComponentDirContext.p_search(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.jndi.toolkit.ctx.PartialCompositeDirContext.search(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.jndi.toolkit.ctx.PartialCompositeDirContext.search(Unknown Source)
    at hudson.plugins.active_directory.LDAPSearchBuilder.search(LDAPSearchBuilder.java:52)
(...)
Jun 4, 2014 7:20:36 AM hudson.plugins.active_directory.ActiveDirectoryUnixAuthenticationProvider retrieveUser
WARNING: Credential exception tying to authenticate against mydomain.com.br domain
org.springframework.security.BadCredentialsException: Failed to retrieve user information for t01brq0009; nested exception is javax.naming.NamingException: [LDAP: error code 1 - 00000000: LdapErr: DSID-0C090627, comment: In order to perform this operation a successful bind must be completed on the connection., data 0, vece]; remaining name 'DC=mydomain,DC=com,DC=br'
    at hudson.plugins.active_directory.ActiveDirectoryUnixAuthenticationProvider.retrieveUser(ActiveDirectoryUnixAuthenticationProvider.java:306)
    at hudson.plugins.active_directory.ActiveDirectoryUnixAuthenticationProvider.retrieveUser(ActiveDirectoryUnixAuthenticationProvider.java:190)
    at hudson.plugins.active_directory.ActiveDirectoryUnixAuthenticationProvider.retrieveUser(ActiveDirectoryUnixAuthenticationProvider.java:134)
    at hudson.plugins.active_directory.AbstractActiveDirectoryAuthenticationProvider.loadUserByUsername(AbstractActiveDirectoryAuthenticationProvider.java:30)
    at hudson.plugins.active_directory.ActiveDirectorySecurityRealm.loadUserByUsername(ActiveDirectorySecurityRealm.java:611)
    at hudson.security.GlobalMatrixAuthorizationStrategy$DescriptorImpl.doCheckName(GlobalMatrixAuthorizationStrategy.java:315)
    at hudson.security.GlobalMatrixAuthorizationStrategy$DescriptorImpl.doCheckName(GlobalMatrixAuthorizationStrategy.java:298)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
(...)
Caused by: javax.naming.NamingException: [LDAP: error code 1 - 00000000: LdapErr: DSID-0C090627, comment: In order to perform this operation a successful bind must be completed on the connection., data 0, vece]; remaining name 'DC=mydomain,DC=com,DC=br'
    at com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtx.mapErrorCode(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtx.processReturnCode(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtx.processReturnCode(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtx.searchAux(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtx.c_search(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtx.c_search(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.jndi.toolkit.ctx.ComponentDirContext.p_search(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.jndi.toolkit.ctx.PartialCompositeDirContext.search(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.jndi.toolkit.ctx.PartialCompositeDirContext.search(Unknown Source)
    at hudson.plugins.active_directory.LDAPSearchBuilder.search(LDAPSearchBuilder.java:52)
    at hudson.plugins.active_directory.LDAPSearchBuilder.searchOne(LDAPSearchBuilder.java:42)
    at hudson.plugins.active_directory.ActiveDirectoryUnixAuthenticationProvider.retrieveUser(ActiveDirectoryUnixAuthenticationProvider.java:260)
    ... 75 more
```

Some things that I've tried:

- Update the com4j dll with the last version
- Change the com4j dll with the older version (I have another server with an old hudson installation and it is working fine)
- Right now I'm trying the last hudson update (3.1.2)

Have anyone encounter this issue that could give me some hint on it?
I will greatly appreciate.

Thanks.

**UPDATE**

- No success with version 3.1.2 =/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So guys, after digging up inside hudson´s folders about the active directory (AD) I've found a file on `[HUDSONFOLDER]\plugins\active-directory\help` called `domain-name-windows.html` so, I open it and there was this precious information (among others):

```
By default, Jenkins uses ADSI to talk to Active Directory, and doing 
this doesn't require the domain name to be configured.
```

And regarding the [ADSI](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa772170.aspx), this link can explain better. Since Hudson and Jenkins are almost the same project, I figure it out that it should work for Hudson as well.

Another thing that I notice is that (as I'm on windows) I had to configure my apache service (`services.msc`) to start using an user from the same AD. Because it is configured by default with `local account` and that way it is not able to make any searches on the AD.

So, thanks anyway to the ones who take time to pay attention to this post.